How does one show that god is logically possible?
How does one show that god (note: not the concept of god) is a logically possible entity? It seems that one could say: well, the definition of god does not contain contradictions or is not incoherent. But this is a claim, and one would have to define the terms clearly to show that there is no contradiction.
As an analogy, in order to show that there are no three positive integers a, b, and c that satisfy the equation a^n + b^n = c^n for any integer value of n greater than 2, a 100 page proof had to be published. Before this, it was not obvious that it was impossible, and one could imagine a set of values that satisfy that equation even if it was impossible for one to exist.
How does one do the same for god?

Assuming that "logically possible" means  ot-contradictory, the issue is that not every possibility is real. There is nothing inconsistent in the idea of unicorn: there are fishes with horn.

@MauroALLEGRANZA yes, but we can easily define a fish and a horn, and then mix those concepts. We also have experiences with fishes and horns. What about a disembodied, timeless, mind? We have no experience with a timeless mind for example, so how do we know it’s possible, even logically?

I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of God, but unfortunately this comment space is too small to contain it...

Generally speaking, we don't 'prove' things exist. We experience them directly or we infer them from other things we experience directly. We don't 'prove' horses exist; we go to a field and see them; we don't 'prove' Tyrannosaurus Rexes exist; we infer their existence from fossil remains. And anything is logically possible unless we prove otherwise. Logic skews towards inclusivity.

@TedWrigley   Didn't physicists prove that the Higgs boson exists?

@Philomath - No, they had to detect it (indirectly based on its decay products and based on statistical analysis of the measurements). That's not a proof.

@TedWrigley so a gibberish statement like “tbf the gf j he drug” is logically possible until proven otherwise? And the math statement I linked as an example is logically possible until proven otherwise?

@Philomath: We infer the existence of the Higgs boson because a lot of other things we actually experience make more sense if the Higgs boson exists. We haven't 'proven' it exists, and in fifty or a hundred years physicists might look back and laugh at us for believing it.

@Syed: Gibberish doesn't carry meaning, so it can't be said to point to something that may or may not exist. For statements that do carry meaning, yes: we have to allow that they are possible unless we can prove they are not. That doesn't mean we have to believe them, but it's poor methodology to preclude an outcome prejudicially.

"We infer the existence of the Higgs boson because a lot of other things we actually experience make more sense if the Higgs boson exists.". Well said, and scalable to the question IMHO.

@TedWrigley timeless is meaningful and so is mine. But how do you know that a timeless mind is logically possible? Why should it be logically possible until proven otherwise? Can you imagine your mind being timeless?

@TedWrigley -- Sorry, I mixed up the language game (in the Wittgensteinian sense) we are playing here. You're right, technically we can't prove anything outside math and logic. We infer the existence of atoms and molecules and I have to infer the existence of this SE and you by the photons that bounce of my screen and hit my retina. In fifty years I might be laughing at the folly of believing it. ;)

@mudskipper (sigh) I should have know better. Technically we are all solipsists...

@Syed: If you don't know what timeless mind is, you should meditate more. Just sayin'…

@TedWrigley or maybe the notion of a timeless mind is incoherent and meditation would be a waste of time

@Syed: Proper empiricism demands an open mind and a willingness to look. If we declare things as incoherent and impossible in order to preclude investigation, then  we're not doing science, we're practicing a faith.

Saying that God exists is, strictly speaking, not a proposition about God.
The proposition is a proposition about language, about the use of words; it merely says that the word "God" -- used as a proper name by religious people -- has a reference. Similarly, "Santa Claus doesn't exist" or "There is no Santa Claus" says that the name "Santa Claus" has no reference in our world.
I don't know who or what religious people (believe they) refer to when using the word "God", but I do know that the meaning of this word is not learned by "defining one's terms". It's trivial to see that in general we don't learn to speak by being given definitions of words in terms of other words, or even by being given any kind of explicit definitions of single words. If you look at the most rigorous science, mathematics, we always start from so-called primitive terms -- that is, undefined terms. The meaning of those terms is only established implicitly by stating some axioms. In general the meaning of our terms is established simply by starting to speak. (Or from a child's perspective, by babbling, listening, and trying to make sense of what we hear.) We also don't know in advance, and cannot easily determine, what the relations are between those initial axioms or statements -- whether they lead to contradictions or not, whether they are mutually dependent or not. The most famous example of this are the development of non-Euclidean geometry and the history of continuum hypothesis. So, it's a nonsensical requirement to require that we always need to start from a position that is, somehow, guaranteed to be free of any contradictions and totally clear.
I imagine that from a religious point of view, the meaning of the word "God" is , similarly, implicitly defined by the stories people tell and have been told and by -- what I'd call -- anchoring events that link particular statements or stories to actual historical events and to personal, intersubjectively shared experiences, and that thereby provide reference points. I don't see any reason why a believer would have to argue that the focal point of those stories, God, is "logically possible", or that those stories are not fatally flawed due to some logical contradictions.  A religion or a world view is something in the light of which their adherents make sense of everyday life -- both of what is happening, how best to describe that, and of how to life, what should be done. You cannot simply step in or out of it like you step in or out of a new suit of clothes.
The idea that our starting point should be totally clear and proven to be free of contradiction is an idee fixe of modern philosophy. The demand that others adopt this point of view can only be seen as an attempt at philosophical intimidation. It's not a reasonable demand.

My perception is that demanding others prove your point falsifiable is a debating technique rather than a philosophical technique.

We have experience with minds.
Many people believe that minds are non-physical, which would make bodies optional.
Timelessness is a simple negation of timefulness, and is no harder to imagine than infinity (and arguably is Infinity applied to the time axis).
The fact that we can imagine something is evidence that we can imagine something. We can also imagine colorless green ideas sleeping furiously, if we work at it.
If we can't produce a falsifiable argument in one direction, I am not convinced we can produce a falsifiable argument in the other direction.

I can imagine a falsifiable argument, and I can imagine someone showing it to be incorrect. I can imagine more useful subjects of inquiry, but quite possibly I am just wrong about that :-)

@ScottRowe: I imagine  you're right.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
